# What is the process after Azure AD B2C signup/login is implemented in a web framework?

Tags: python, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am now able to register/login a user via Azure AD B2C using the `msal` library following the sample code [sign-in-b2c](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-django-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in-b2c) for the Django framework. But what is the process now to make use of all of this in the application itself?

Do I need to create a user model saving the users `sub` or ID from Azure? Is it possible to make use of the roles, groups or permissions that some framework provides? I see one can create API connectors in Azure that trigger when a user has registered.

In general I know very little about what to do "next", could you explain to me what I need to do for authorization at the application level or an general explanation for how things will need to be done now that the user is not created or saved by the app?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on the application you are making. Ideally your application should store as little user information as realistic, instead getting that information from the token fresh each time. This limits conflicts that may arise where the user is updated in B2C, but not in your application or vice versa, and limits the number of locations personal information is stored.

Ideally, your application shouldn't be doing any authorization other than ensuring that the token it received did in fact come from your B2C tenant, the specifics of that will depend on the type of token being sent. Any information your application gets from the token and doesn't need to store long term should only be stored for the duration of the user's session with the application and shouldn't be persisted to permanent storage.

If you want to store additional information that doesn't make sense to store in B2C (history, preferences, maybe user roles), then associate them with the users ObjectID somewhere your application can access them.

Handling roles can be tricky, as B2C doesn't out of the box offer support for them. If you are only using a single application, I'd recommend just doing all roles/groups/permissions stuff in your application as the Django framework is more set up for that than B2C. If doing multiple applications, it may make more sense, especially if they share that permission information, to do things in B2C as it means you can update a user's permissions in a single space. I haven't used [this example](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/groups) but it details using B2C to manage user groups. I also am not too familiar with interfacing B2C permissions with Django, but perhaps others can help if you decide to go that route